# Get-ADUser AccountExpirationDate

Tags: powershell

I am having some difficulties with the output of the Account Expiration Date from some users in our AD.

This is the code I am using:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties AccountExpirationDate
```

Problem is when I have a user in AD that has not set a expiration date it shows blank. I want that it shows 'Never Expires' because that is the case. When I check a user with expiration date it will show me the exact expiry date.

I also tried with if else statement, but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ralph

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Properties PasswordNeverExpires`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way could be to also ask for the LDAP `accountExpires` property, which is a numeric value.
If that user property equals to 0 or 9223372036854775807, then the account never expires.

```
Get-ADUser -Properties AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires | 
Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, 
              @{Name = 'AccountExpirationDate'
                Expression = {
                    if ($_.accountExpires -gt 0 -and $_.accountExpires -ne 9223372036854775807) { $_.AccountExpirationDate }
                    else { 'Never Expires' }
                }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Test if the value is `$null`:

```
$user = Get-ADUser $username -Properties AccountExpirationDate |Select SAMAccountName,@{Name='AccountExpiration'; Expression={if($null -eq $_.AccountExpirationDate){'Never Expires'}else{$_.AccountExpirationDate}}}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias! Works like a charm. Only one thing left now... How can I show only 'Never Expires' instead of @{Account Expiry Date=Never Expires}. I tried to remove the string from the object like AccountExpirationDate).AccountExpirationDate.

Comment: Pipe to `Select-Object -Expand AccountExpirationDate`

Comment: Looks like that's not going to work for me. Invalid argument.

Comment: Sorry, that should've been `Select-Object -Expand AccountExpiration`